# At and To can be used together?

Tags: grammar

I have read these lines on a blog and I have doubt :

> Look at to the sky..

I guess we can not use at and to together.
What is right?

Comment: No. Not like that. Look at the sky, look to the sky are both ok.
Please visit http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "look at" for most things.  "Look to" means to hope or expect to get help from someone or something. As in:

> Children look to their parents for guidance.

I would only say "Look to the sky" if you meant it in a metaphorical, possibly religious way. And "At to" doesn't make sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

"Look at to the sky.." Would be improper. You are correct in assuming that `at` and `to`cannot be used together. Either `look to the sky` or `look at the sky` could be used interchangeably in this case.`Look at the sky` is a far more common wording. In my opinion, `look to` has a mystical, poetic sort of feel to it and is not commonly used in everyday speech.